# Как добавить ресурсные файлы в jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
Не добавляются ресурсные файлы в jar при сборке мавеном:
- answers.txt
- questions.txt
- rightAnswers.txt

В pom.xml описаны:
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>questions.txt</include>
                <include>answers.txt</include>
                <include>rightAnswers.txt</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

Чтение в Main.class первый вариант:
    FileReader readerQuestions = new FileReader("questions.txt");
    FileReader readerAnswers = new FileReader("answers.txt");
    FileReader readerRightAnswers = new FileReader("rightAnswers.txt");

Второй вариант:
    FileReader readerQuestions = new FileReader(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("questions.txt"))));
    FileReader readerAnswers = new FileReader(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("answers.txt"))));
    FileReader readerRightAnswers = new FileReader(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("rightAnswers.txt"))));
```

[Реп - https://github.com/MichelShumaher/System-of-Testing.git](https://github.com/MichelShumaher/System-of-Testing.git)

[image: Структура проекта]

Comment: Помимо указания ссылки на репозиторий укажите как-то структуру проекта в самом вопрос, чтобы можно было её видеть без перехода по ссылке. Хотя бы скриншот из IDE приложите. А то ссылки могут помереть либо вы поменяете код в репозитории и вопрос станет бессмысленным, т.к. в нём не будет возможности воспроизведения проблемы.

Comment: Также укажите, чем производите сборку.